# C# Outlook VSTO cannot start process due to permissions

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto

I created a VSTO with C# and I want to invoke a simple EXE file from the Program Files (x86) folder. The VSTO code is extremely simple and it just tries to invoke the EXE file with Process.Start from System.Diagnostics. On a computer with an administrator user, the code works fine. However, when I try it on a computer with a non-administrator user, the VSTO apparently has no permissions to start the EXE. There are no errors, but it simply doesn't do anything.

Does anybody how to fix this permissions issue? Thanks in advance!

The code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Program\\here.exe");
    info.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Program\\";
    info.UseShellExecute = true;
    Process.Start(info);
}
```

Comment: Just right click Outlook and run it as administrator.

Comment: My guess is there is something your program is trying to do that would require write access to the working directory (maybe logging?).

Comment: There is nothing special going on in the exe program. No logging either. It might as well be an empty windows form window...

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT set the working directory to the `Program files (x86)` directory.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
     ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\here.exe");
     //info.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Program\\";
     info.WorkingDirectory = SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
     info.UseShellExecute = true;
     Process.Start(info);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference whether I set the working directory or not, unfortunately.

Comment: What if you set the working directory to the user's document folder?

Comment: interestingly enough, I was trying that yesterday and on one particular computer there was no documents folder. I don't know if it was deleted by accident, but that windows machine was running perfectly happy without the documents folder and it was causing my program to crash, so I decided to run the program from the AppData folder instead. No permissions problems there, but this is only a temporary solution.

Comment: Wait, so if you set the working directory to the AppData folder, then it's working?

Comment: I am actually not setting the working directory at all anymore. I just placed the exe in the %appdata%/[programname] folder (instead of program files) and provide the full path to the exe. It works like that.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that the Program Files folder requires admin privileges. You can't modify anything if you (user) don't have sufficient privileges for that. And if the target .exe file tries to create or write something there it fails to run.

If you run the code in a x86 based OS system the path will be different. There is no `Program Files (x86)` folder on such OSs.

Also there is no need to set the `WorkingDirectory` property if you specify the full path to the executables.

Comment: I have a piece of code that detects the computer's architecture and sets the path accordingly. I excluded it from my example to isolate the issue, which is that the exe doesn't even open. User's must have at least read permission to the program files folder, otherwise no program would be able to run. If you want to try to replicate the issue, you can simply try to open a blank windows form.

Comment: Do you get the same results with e Windows Forms application?

Comment: Not sure what e Windows Forms are, sorry for my ignorance. The exe is a separate windows forms project... I gave up on this permissions problem for now due to lack of time. I still want to be able to run the software from the program files directory, because that's where I am storing the vsto and manifest files. But, to get it to work for now until I find a solution, I changed the vsto to open the exe file from the user's appdata folder instead.